# Create SQL table from an Excel file

Tags: mysql, excel, database

Can any one help me with SQL??
My supervisors wants me to create a SQL script that reads the Excel file(Sheet1) and than creates the corresponding table in a particular database.

a. The script must takes the file name (location) as a parameter.
b. The created table must have the same name as the file.
c. The script must create the table with a primary key.
d. Every type of data that is inside the Excel file must be converted to varchar.

Sincerelly I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please tag the database name you want to use..

Comment: I will run the script on a local database, for example DbTest

Comment: No, i am asking database like Oracle, Mysql or Sql Server. Which database are you going to use..?

Comment: ohh sorry. I will use MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the script using following steps.

```
1. Convert excel file to csv format. 
2. Use SUBSTRING_INDEX() to extract file name from file path and use it as table name. 
3. Load First row to get the list of columns and to create table.
4. Load the data. Refer [http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/load-delimited-data-csv-excel-into-mysql-server][1]

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "file path" INTO TABLE test
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (id, name);
```

Comment: Thnx for helping me.

Comment: Please vote the answer if you really find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks :) And One more suggestion: you can extract the column names dynamically from excel file.